# how to make this code asynchronous with await in python

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm trying to write my first asynchronous code with `aiohttp`, but somehow I don't understand where shall the program `await` in this example:

```
async def fetch_cookies():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post('https://some.website', data=payload) as resp:
            #assert resp.status == '200'
            #print(resp.headers)
            #await resp.cookies
            cookies = resp.cookies
            for v in cookies.values():
                if len(v.value) == 32 :
                    jsessionid = v.value
                elif len(v.value) == 36:
                    token = v.value
            #print(await resp.text())
            return {'JSESSIONID': jsessionid, 'Token': token}


payload = getting_credentials('config.txt')
result = asyncio.run(fetch_cookies())
```

I tried awaiting for cookies, but it throws an `TypeError`
If you also have some suggestions about the reading materials that breaks down the asynchronous programming in Python, I'd be grateful.
For instance, now I'm not sure that if I write a function `func1` that makes a `POST` request with the cookies extracted from `fetch_cookies`, `func1` won't run before `fetch_cookies`.
Many thanks!

Comment: The `await` is somewhat implicit in the `async with` here. That's already putting a "breakpoint" into the code during which you could do other things. There are simply no other things to do for your code at the moment…

Comment: @deceze Thank you! I didn't know that `await` is implied in async with